# AWS-S3 and AWS-CloudFront With React routes, multi application

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, react-router, amazon-cloudfront

I have the following scenario.

- S3 bucket and several directories, one directory for each react application
- All the paths of each react application start with the name of the directory hosted in the s3 bucket

For example:

S3 Directories

```
|--/
   |--/first-app/
   |--/second-app/
```

React routes of `first-app`

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Empty,
    exact: true,
  },
  {
    path: '/first-app',
    component: Layout,
    routes: [
      { path: '/first-app/create', component: CreateCommponent},
      { path: '/first-app/login', component: Login },
      { path: '/first-app/logout', component: Logout },
    ],
  },
]
```

React routes of `second-app`

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Empty,
    exact: true,
  },
  {
    path: '/second-app',
    component: Layout,
    routes: [
      { path: '/second-app/create', component: OtherComponent},
      { path: '/second-app/login', component: Login },
      { path: '/second-app/logout', component: Logout },
    ],
  },
]
```

**How do I make cloudFront serve each application in each directory independently but under the same domain?**

`https://my.domain.com/first-app` >> serve react application middle index.html of first-app

`https://my.domain.com/second-app`>> serve react application middle index.html of second-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Lambda@Edge in order to manipulate the request parameters before sending the request to the bucket. here is a similar example: [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=812462#812462)

Comment: This would add additional costs to the operation.

Comment: There is definitely no better solution